# Material ViewPager Tap on Back to Exit Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toolbar

Unable to `exit` Pager activity when I do tap on `back` using Florent's ViewPager [Library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager)

I am calling `PagerActivity` like this :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here (in **PagerActivity**.java), I am getting `back icon` by default at **top left** corner, but when I do `tap` on it nothing `happens`.

like this:

[image]

PagerActivity.java

```
public class PagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialViewPager materialViewPager;
    View headerLogo;
    ImageView headerLogoContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager);

        //4 onglets
        final int tabCount = 4;

        //les vues définies dans @layout/header_logo
        headerLogo = findViewById(R.id.headerLogo);
        headerLogoContent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headerLogoContent);

        //le MaterialViewPager
        this.materialViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);
        this.materialViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {                   

            .........
        this.materialViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(tabCount);
        //relie les tabs au viewpager
        this.materialViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(this.materialViewPager.getViewPager());
    }

    ......

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                // onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_pager.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialViewPager"
        app:viewpager_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:viewpager_enableToolbarElevation="true"
        app:viewpager_headerAlpha="0.6"
        app:viewpager_headerHeight="200dp"
        app:viewpager_hideLogoWithFade="true"
        app:viewpager_hideToolbarAndTitle="true"
        app:viewpager_logo="@layout/header_logo"
        app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/material_view_pager_pagertitlestrip_newstand"
        app:viewpager_logoMarginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your PagerActivity class.

Comment: add a click listener to the action bar item to exit from your activity

Comment: Try onBackPressed() method and show PagerActivity

Comment: I know normally we use finish or onBackPressed() to leave an activity, when do tap on back icon... but facing this issue when using Florent's ViewPager lib only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add below code in `PagerActivity`. because `MaterialViewPager` library have ToolBar/Actionbar included so you have to set it first.

```
this.materialViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);
toolbar = materialViewPager.getToolbar();
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

after that use below method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method to your `PagerActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I know normally we use above method to finish activity, when do tap on back icon... but facing this issue when using Florent's ViewPager lib only